# How to give permissions(administering permissions) to different users in sharepoint

Tags: 2007, administration

How to give permissions(administering permissions) to different users in sharepoint LIKE for a user, for a manager, for a system engineer and so on. I want differences in their accessibility to the site. How do I administer it? Do i have to use any tool or language? 
Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Site Actions` button on the top-right of your page and click on `Site Settings`

From here you can click on either `People and Groups` or `Advanced Permissions` to see your users and groups.  It also allows you to create new groups/users and set permissions at site-level.

Once you've created groups and users that you can work with, you can now set permissions on individual libraries,folder/files and sites by either using the site's `Site Settings`, or in the case of a library, just open the drop down menu for it and select `Manage Permissions`.  From here you can add in your groups and users and specify what permissions you want them to have.

**EDIT** to add to what was discovered in comments to this answer since you are also looking for Database permissions:

Assuming that your database is being run by a Microsoft SQL Server, you can use something like SQL Server Management Studio. Just make sure you match the right versions. For example, SQL Server 2008 which you can download here : microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593 This tool will let you manage your databases and permissions.

SQL Server Management Studio is a GUI tool, no programming language required. You log into your server and you're presented with a tree view of everything available to you. Find your database in the tree, right-click > click on Properties and a window will pop up where you can click on Permissions and view/modify the users' permissions. There a lot you can do, and you can also run SQL Queries if you want.

Also, here are some good tutorials to get you started:

Basic beginner's guide : [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934498(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934498%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Logging in : http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-use-microsoft-sql-server-2008-to-connect-to-your-database/

Changing user permissions: http://www.fasthosts.co.uk/knowledge-base/?article_id=1170

Another on permissions (see answer) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998634/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-grant-privileges-to-a-username

Comment: I know this part of setting permissions. This works fine when I have data stored in a sharepoint list. But how do I set permissions when I have my data stored in a database?

Comment: @celebrateceleb Ah, for this you need to log into the SQL Server with the SQL management studio. You can't do this from SharePoint.

Comment: Is there any tool to do it? Or it should be hard coded?

Comment: @celebrateceleb Assuming that your database is being run by a Microsoft SQL Server, you can use something like `SQL Server Management Studio`.  Just make sure you match the right versions.  For example, SQL Server 2008 which you can download here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593   This tool will let you manage your databases and permissions.  What are you running to host your databases?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. Is SQL Server Management Studio a tool or do I have to give queries/use programming language to administer rights?

Comment: @celebrateceleb It's a GUI tool, no programming language required.  You log into your server and you're presented with a tree view of everything available to you.  Find your database in the tree, right-click > click on `Properties` and a window will pop up where you can click on `Permissions` and view/modify the users' permissions.  There a lot you can do, and you can also run SQL Queries if you want.

Comment: Thanx:) i ll look into Management Studio

Comment: @celebrateceleb Great!  I edited my answer with more info and some links to get you started on working with SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288440%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It is from Microsoft's website. It explains "permission" groups that already exist that you can access and set users to and also explains how you can create custom groups based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add this user as one of the Site Collection Administrators for the CA Site.  So from any of the CA pages navigate to `Site Actions -> Site Settings`

In the `Site Settings` page, in the Users and Permissions section, click the `Site Collection Administrators` link

In the `Site Collection Administrators` field enter the account of the `user` and then click .

Follow this article [Creating New/Additional SharePoint Farm Administrators](http://www.mukalian.com/blog/post/2009/06/26/Creating-NewAdditional-SharePoint-Farm-Administrators.aspx) to know step by step approach..

More over look Share point help documents [Manage SharePoint groups](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-sharepoint-groups-HA010100146.aspx) and [Permissions for site collection administrators](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/permissions-for-site-collection-administrators-HA101943260.aspx).

Hope this help

Comment: I know this part of setting permissions. This works fine when I have data stored in a sharepoint list. But how do I set permissions when I have my data stored in a database?